International trade equilibria with sanctions
I need to insert this diagram about international terms of trade in my project but since it is a png file when you get to zoom in the image looses its definition. I was thinking to use {tizkpicture} but to be honest I don't know where to start since it is a complex diagram. I would appreciate if you will be able to provide me the code to plot a diagram looking the most possible similar to the original one. Thank you in advance.


Welcome to TeX.SX! Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See minimal working example (MWE) for what needs to go into such a document.  Since you've identified tikz as helpful, searching for that should get you started.

You may need to add some code compilable about what you have try. Then we can find where you stuck and provide help.

The other way to go is to produce a vector image in something like Inkscape, which has a gentler learning curve at the beginning. (Inkscape is probably not ideal for a plot, but I'm sure there are suitable GUI programmes out there.) If you really want to code it, also take a look at pgfplots.

whatever application you used to generate the png file could probably generate a scalable version such as pdf. so go back to that application and save in a different format

Welcome // It's not very complex. Please see these two solutions to similar problems: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/623391/245790 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708455/245790 . If you step through them and look up new stuff here https://tikz.dev/ you should be able to get most things done.
